# Creating a vertical scrollable table

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

Basically I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to code this. I want to have a table/grid. On the left side my user inputs some basic data, the rest of my columns my user must tick some check boxes. Only thing is I'm reading this data from an api so I don't know how much there will be. I want the rest of the columns to be the same size as my first one but scrollable. How do I go about this as I've tried a few different ways and nothing seems to work. I've attached a little image of what I'm trying to achieve.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make the list overflow: scroll. Add as many menus as you need. Here's a good starting place:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That should help thank you very much. It was more the method of doing this that was confusing me, I was putting tables inside tables to try and do it.

Comment: @DanMurphy use overflow-y:scroll; instead of overflow:scroll for less scroll wills.